# PHP How to show and link all viewed sites of a intern session?

Tags: php, wordpress, path, linked-list, history

I'm searching for a code, that shows and links users the clicking path of the viewed sites of the actually session.

I am not searching for a classical breadcrumb, that shows the hierarchy of categories. Only the clicking path history of the actually intern session without categories structure.

Code in wordpress page.php and single.php:

```
<?php 
   echo $_SESSION['page'];
?>
```

Code in wordpress functions.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['page']= "{$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']} 
https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
?>
```

The code shows the last viewed site and the actually.
But i want to show all referrers sites since sessions start and link to it.

Comment: Really nobody can help? :(

Comment: Maybe someone can give me a link or an example? I don't get it...